# swap two columns and rows in screen assembly emu8086

Tags: assembly, x86-16, emu8086

How I can swap two columns and two rows on-screen with the assembly emu8086
What are the service code and the registers used?

I want to enter two numbers ex(1,3) and the program swap between the row which has this number in the screen and the same thing to columns.

Of course, the screen will have information.

Comment: When you want to swap two characters, which are displayed on text-mode screen, you can  use BIOS videoservice [SET CURSOR POSITION](http://www.ctyme.com/intr/rb-0087.htm) and then 
[READ CHARACTER AND ATTRIBUTE AT CURSOR POSITION](http://www.ctyme.com/intr/rb-0098.htm) in a double loop through screen columns and rows.  Or remember which coordinates you have used to display them, and then swap them with instruction XCHG.

Comment: @vitsoft Thank you very much , the problem is solved :).